# What is the reason for two classes storefront_woocommerce and storefront

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to ask perhaps newbie question.Recently I started with woocommerce and when i looked at source code of the  current storefront theme , i saw 2 major classes: storefront and storefront_woocommerce.They have quite different hooks when constructing.Can someone enlight me with specific reasons behind splitting the logic into 2 classes.I'm trying to track the idea.
Thanks.

Comment: As to what I've investigated so far class Storefront is the main Storefront theme class and class Storefront_Woocommerce is the Storefront Woocommerce Integration class.Admittedly that's a little step front for me.